# Axios request in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

In Flutter/ Dart, I want to pass a method as an optional parameter to a Post request in additional to other fields.

How to achieve this in Flutter/ Dart ?

Please note the sample Code from .net using axios type call

```
                   formData.append('uploadType', data.uploadType);
                    $axios.$post('/api/someUrl', formData, {
                    params: {},
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                        Accept: "application/json"
                    },
                     
                    onMethod,// Here's a function that needs to be passed.
                    cancelToken: cancelToken.token
                });
            },
```

I have tried with MultiPart request and there is no option to send a method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I give you an example using formdata in dart:

```
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('Api/SomeURL'));
    //all field you can add here 
String temp = await medthod();
    request.fields.addAll({
          'Description': temp,
          'Title': 'Hello World'
        });
        http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // I print the result in the console, if you like to use it plase create a object dart
          print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
        }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

I note something, the method not using `void`, it must be return a type, just like a `String`or `int` or something more.

P/S: String temp = await medthod(); this line must be run first and await until done so after that you can use temp as an argument like you want. Remember the method must return a String.

Comment: Hi Xuan, 
I'm having no issues with form field data, I want to pass a method as an argument of  HTTP post call. That's the issue. Can you help me with it .?

Comment: I just eidt my post so you check it and try. Hope this help you. @J.Dhinesh

Comment: ok. I will check on this.

Comment: The modified answer was also not worked. Can you share me a similar sample API call using fake API's?

Comment: With request.fields.addAll({}) , the method has to be passed as a key value pair . But I want to pass a method directly and not using format of key value pair.

Can you provide suggestion on it or a simple sample using Fake API was fine.

Comment: Okay, public your API, then give me, i will do a short example code for you.

Comment: The API can't be made public , With the help of existing Fake Api available can you share examples

Comment: Sure ! Let me repair an API to do demo for you.